# Raw Input not working on funciont/while

Tags: python

This part of my code is giving me problems with the raw_input. The thing is, the terminal does not detect any problems and the program runs, however it never asks the user for input, the program just prints what it has to print at the beginning and then exits for some odd reasons, everything inside the while is not executed. Thanks in advance.

Heres the code:

```
options_secondscenario = ['Whats going on out there?',  'So what now?']

def second_scenario():
    print "Conversation 1"
    print "Conversation 2"
    print "Conversation 3"
    print options_secondscenario
    option = options_secondscenario[1]
    while next == option:
        choice_secondscenario = raw_input("> ")

        if next == 'Whats going on out there?':
            print "Conversation 4"      
        elif next == 'So what now':
        third_scenario()
        else: 
            dead()

second_scenario()
```

Comment: `next` is a built-in function in python. You haven't actually defined what you want `next` to be (presumably, it's a variable that should hold some value). Since `'So what now?'` is never equal to the function `next`, the while loop is never entered, and nothing past the first few lines is printed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next == option` is never true, because `next` is a built-in function and is never equal to a string. In fact, this would actually be an error in Python 3. So your `while` loop is never entered.

Comment: God dammit, good to know guys, I accidentally put this function all over my program and now I need to change it, thanks guys